# Terminate ros2 nodes in bash

Tags: bash, terminate, ros2

I currently have a bash script which launches my ros2 nodes.This works perfectly fine. I now tried to start the script as a background task and write the output into a file. When doing so, I am unable to terminate the nodes at a later point. Previously I terminated it by hitting `Ctrl + C` in the terminal and all nodes stopped. I tried to do same by saving the PID when starting the script and then killing it afterwards, however the nodes keep running.

Is there any possibility to stop all nodes started by the script? Stopping all ros2 nodes is not possible because I launch multiple in parallel.

#### Start

```sh
"./${SCRIPTFILE}" > $LOGFILE  & 
echo $! > $PIDFILE
```

#### Stop

```sh
kill -TERM $(cat $PIDFILE) 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `kill -TERM $(cat $PIDFILE) 2> /dev/null` it sends a SIGTERM, which is more of a cautious way to see if a shutdown is possible not endangering the integrity of open DBs or files, but it can be blocked or handled otherwise. If you want to kill a process regardless of it's state then use:

```
kill -9 -TERM $(cat $PIDFILE) 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. All nodes are still running. This is probably because ros2 is actually running in a separate process. However when running in terminal (not in background), all nodes close after ^C

Comment: Yeah if the script kicks off another process, than you might have to get the PIDs for that before executing the kill. Can you do a unique and unambigious 'ps aux | grep ros2' or alike that definitely fives you the line of and 'awk -F' the process id from it - then this would definitely end the life ov the nodes ;-)

Comment: I thought of this as well but this would kill all nodes not just the one started by the script. right?

Comment: Yeah most probably - do the processes differ from eachother in any way when you go for 'ps aux | grep <processname>' I was thinking perhaps you can grep and awk anything from the process overview - you only have to find any differenz in the output somwhere, that you can refer to when killing it.